# Jquery botao com contador de cliques

Tags: jquery

Bom dia. Eu tenho no meu html uma tabela dinamica com alguns dados vindo do sql, entre eles um campo "quantidade disponivel" e um botao que a cada clique,faca uma requisicao ajax e diminua a quantidade disponivel

```
"<tr>";
             "<td>{$key2}</td>";
            "<td data-nome={$value2} id='contador'>{$value2}</td>";
            "<td ><input type='button' data-campo='{$key2}'  data-modulo='{$p_arrPagina['idmodulo']}' data-tabela='{$p_idtabela}'  class='addcampos btn btn-primary' value='Adicionar + 1'></td>";
            "</tr>";
```

Preciso de um codigo jquery para conseguir mostrar ao usuario que o valor esta sendo decrementado. O que eu fiz ate agora foi

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.addcampos', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var valor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-nome]').data('nome');
        var texto = $(this).closest('tr').find('#contador');
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var idmodulo = $(this).data('modulo');
                var idtabela = $(this).data('tabela');
                var campo = $(this).data('campo');

        $.ajax({
         url: 'localhost/controllers/recebido.php',

         type: 'POST',
         data: {    'idmodulo' : idmodulo,
                    'idtabela': idtabela,
                    'campo' : campo },
        success: function(response){
                valor--;
            console.log(valor);
            var novoTexto = texto.html(valor);
                        }
        })
        .done(function(dados) {

        })
        .fail(function() {
         alert('ocorreu um erro');
        })
});
```

Estou tentando decrementar da variavel valor. porem ela so funciona a primeira vez que clico no botao

Comment: Acho que o problema está sendo que a variável `novoTexto` não atualiza o elemento que a variavel "valor" se refere.

Answer (score -1):

resolvi apenas modificando a variavel valor. Agora ela se chama quantidade e consegui pegar o valor dela com o seguinte codigo 
`var quantidade = $(this).closest('tr').find("#quantidade").text();`